# Catch implicit insertions and deletions into a join table performed by JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa, count, many-to-many, listener

I have `NEWS` table in many-to-many relation with `TAGS` one (join table called `NEWS_TAG`) and the corresponding entities.

The task is to obtain tags, with count of news that are tagged with it. One can simply use `COUNT` function in every selection, but in order to increase performance I added `NEWS_COUNT` column to `TAGS` table.

`NEWS_COUNT` is changed when a news with corresponding tag is persisted or removed from a DB.

How to manage the 
 `NEWS_COUNT` attribute with JPA? It would be great if I could somehow find out when `NEWS_TAG` table is modified by the persistence provider and change the `NEWS_COUNT` of tags accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding the unnecessary filed (`NEWS_COUNT`) you have to update the entity per each *remove* or *add* operations and this decreases the performance. You didn't need to that field  at all, if you have configured the tables and entities properly, base of collection type you use for the associative entity you may get the count of `NEWS` of each `TAG` by `size()` function: `tag.news.size()` or you can use `count` function within JPQL.

However I don't know about the scenario and maybe you do *CRUD* operations rarely but you get the counts too much, in this case the best way is to use `TRIGGERS` to update that field (if your DB system supports it) in this way `NEWS_COUNT` is always updated and you don't need to do anything in your application layer. if you don't use a mechanism inside your DB system to update `NEWS_COUNT` field then in your application layer you *have to* update the entity and increase or decrease the field for each `add` or `remove` operations.

Comment: Yes, my case is "rarely add, often search". 
`add` and `remove` is only half of the problem. Next half is actually `update`.
So, really, as for me triggers are good for it, but maybe one can suggest a better solution.